# Error occurs when installing rJava

Tags: java, rjava

When I try to install the `rJava` package the following error occurs:

> Error in ibrary(rJava) : could not find function "ibrary" >
>   library("rJava", lib.loc="~/R/R-3.4.0/library") Error: package or
>   namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:  .onLoad in loadNamespace() für
>   'rJava' fehlgeschlagen, Details:   Aufruf: fun(libname, pkgname)
>   Fehler: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry >

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this, start by checking if java is installed or not. Then check if `JAVA_HOME` variable is set or not by `echo $JAVA_HOME`.

If it returns nothing and java is installed, then do `export $JAVA_HOME=/your/path`.

Installation instructions are available [here](https://github.com/hannarud/r-best-practices/wiki/Installing-RJava-(Ubuntu)).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to uninstall Java.

Then download and install a new version of Java this should set your **JAVA_HOME**.

Now try installing rJava.